# Creating climbing ladders with webbing strap

Tags: rock-climbing

I have a webbing spool (some meters long) and would like to create climbing ladders out of it.

Could I attach some single bar buckles+tie knots on the extremes to make loops?
Is that a bad idea? The safety of the climber would not depend on it, that is, she would still be attached to a rope.

What kind of buckle would be most appropriate?

Comment: Are you talking about making your own étrier for aid climbing? If so, then doing a web search on 'étrier diy "aid climbing"' turns up several relevant pages. That's not to say that we can't have it as a Q&A here.

Comment: @BenCrowell: yep, exactly that. Maybe some additional info would be useful here. Like pitfalls, best material, ...